# Tools which will generate the class from database design

Tags: mysql

Is there any tool which will generate the class, from our database design in .net.

Comment: What programming language (PHP, Perl, .Net, Java)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a great commercial tool, have a look at http://www.codesmithtools.com/

It contains templates for a variety of ORM frameworks. might need to check mySQL support on some of these.

(I am not affiliated with them, I just like their tools)